# Convert a values in a column from 'cm' to 'm' using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have got a column (B) that contains a value say 543678. I wrote a formula:

`=Convert(543678,"cm","m")`

This has converted the value for me but I have got 1000's of rows with an arbitrary numbers how can I do that using a macro ?

There are multiple columns like Position / Height / Length / Width .

I'm sorry if the question is repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to convert the values "in place", then select the cells and run this macro:

```
Sub ChangeInPlace()
    For Each r In Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        v = r.Value
        If v <> "" Then
            If IsNumeric(v) Then
                r.Value = v / 100
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a reputation to make it +1 that is what i needed as my answer .. Thanks a ton to you guys :)

Answer (score 1):

The [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) equivalent to use your `CONVERT` formula is something like this (to populate all cells to the right of `A2:Ax` where *x* is the last used cell)

*code*

```
Sub QuickConvert()
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Range([a2], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
rng1.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONVERT(RC[-1],""cm"",""m"")"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enter the formula into a cell and then simply drag down from the bottom right of the cell and it will apply the formula to the columns:

[image: DragDown]